# laravel-8 whreRelation says Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'relation' in 'where clause'

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

Laravel version:8.36.2

Article

- id

RelationalArticle

- article_id
- product_id

Product

- id

article hasMany relational_article.

product belongsTo relational_article

When I make

```
Product::whereRelation('relational_article', 'relational_article_id', '=', $article_id)->get();
```

I mean I want to retrieve products from article_id.

Then I got

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'relation' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `products` where `relation` = relational_articles and `products`.`deleted_at` is null)
```

What should I check for it?

Comment: `whereRelation()` will add `WHERE relation = ` to your query, You are looking for `whereHas()` https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

Comment: relational_article is the relation name in your model?

Answer (score 0):

Article and Product should have a 'belongsToMany' relationship;

Your intermediate table

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('article_product', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('article_id')->constrained();
            $table->foreignId('product_id')->constrained();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Article.php

```
public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
    }
```

Product.php

```
public function articles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Article::class);
    }
```

All products that belong to article with id of 1

```
$article = App\Models\Article::find(1)
$article->products
```

Answer (score 0):

You created pivot table for Article and Product model but you used belongsTo and hasMany in your relationships. This is wrong because because you are looking into oneTomany instead of manyToMany relationship. So do this instead

in Article.php model

```
public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
    }
```

in Product.php model

```
public function articles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Article::class);
    }
```

in your controller
do this if you want to get all articles and products

```
public function getArticleById($article_id){    
  $article = App/Model/Article::with('products')->where('id',$article_id)-get()
  return $article
}
```